# How to read every value of a UISlider regardless of how quickly the slider is moved?

Tags: swift, uislider

I need to read each and every value of a `UISlider`. When I print the value of the slider in the debug area you will see that every value is incremented by 1 when moving the slider at slow-medium pace.

[image: Slider values at slow-medium pace]

However when I move the slider fast the values jump in large steps as seen below:

[image: Slider values at fast pace]

Is there anyway I can read the value of a slider with every step regardless of the speed at which it is moved? (preferably in swift)

code:

```
@IBAction func didMoveFeedbackSlider(sender: UISlider) {

    let currentValue = sender.value
    var currentValueInt = Int(ceil(currentValue))

    print("slider value: \(currentValueInt)")

}
```

Comment: Afaik, the slider is continuous by default (`isContinuous` property), so this seems like a weird behavior given that we assume it is a property of the slider. Is it possible that it's a property the controlling device rather than the slider, e.g., of you moving your mouse (mouse update rate?) very quickly? Have you tested on actual touch device? Also, have you tried this behavior for different `UIControlEvents`? (E.g. explicitly using event `ValueChanged`: `yourSlider.addTarget(..., forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)`?).

Comment: I've tested on an iPhone and the value again jumps in steps when moved fast. I also tried adding a target to the slider programmatically rather than connecting an `IBAction` via the storyboard and this made no difference.

Comment: Do you HAVE to use a slider? I am not familiar with sliders, but I know with a UIScrollView I am able to do exactly what you are asking, but I don't know how you would like your UI setup.

Comment: It needs to be a `UISlider`. I will create a screen recording showing what the problem is, but it all comes down to the fact that values are skipped when the slider is moved fast.

Comment: Where are you printing these values?

Comment: Probably the problem is that this are the real slider values and the only thing you need is to display gradually the values not directly. Many scripts are doing so.

Comment: And if you detect negative value, you can just change the slider value to the exact place where this occurs.

Comment: "I need to read each and every value of a UISlider" I doubt it. "I've made an algorithm" It sounds like _that_ is the problem. Show it.

Comment: @matt I've removed reference to the algorithm as its being called after the lines of code I have now included, the issue lies within the code provided

Comment: Cool! Okay, let's try to figure out how you are getting that negative value. What I would suggest is that you debug your `didMoveFeedbackSlider`. Add some logging where if `currentValueInt` comes out negative, you log `currentValue` as well. Let's try to find out how this problem is arising. The problem for me is that I see a negative value in your _interface_ but I don't see that anywhere in the logging. So where is the disconnect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, if you want to follow your algorithm here is a possible solution

```
var value:Int = 0
func readSliderValue(val:Int) {
    while(value != val) {
        value = value + (val < value ? -1 : 1) // or use +=
        print(value)
    }
}
```

***But*** Probably Matt is right and the problem is in the design and/or algorithm.

Why the values are not sequential: The slider represents the actual value of the slider by your mouse/finger position. When you move your finger really fast as on your video/gif the internal process that scans for your finger position/gesture is slower than your finger. So between two checks of the internal algorithms for finger position it(your finger) crossed more than one position of the slider. So the idea of the slider is not to show you how your finger got there, but where it is now. So the slider is working correctly, from it's creators perspective :)

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed!